# The Art of Electronics exercise 1.19

Tags: inductor, basic, books, reference

I'm reading *The Art of Electronics(3rd)*, and I'm just stuck with exercise 1.19. Here is the question:

> Explain why L∝n² for an inductor consisting of a coil of n turns of
>   wire, maintaining fixed diameter and length as n is varied.

I'm not expecting a long complete mathematical explaination, because the book only gives me a little information, claiming that that should be enough.

My idea: I∝1/n(because practically a wire does have some resistance), and V∝n. As a result, L=V/I∝n². But I also notice that an ideal wire shouldn't have any resistance. So I'm confused now…

Comment: It has nothing to do with resistance. But a magnetic field.

Comment: If it helps, that 'fixed diameter and length' refers to the coil former the wire is being wound on, **not** to the wire that's being wound. So if n doubles, the length of wire doubles.

Comment: @EugeneSh. So the current through the inductor doesn't change, and the "back EMF" is increased to n², due to some changes in the magnetic field?

Comment: @EugeneSh. **Theoretically**, current I has nothing to do with n, but **practically**, it does(I ∝ 1/n because r ∝ n, where r is neglected in the theory). So the theory tells us L ∝ n², while experiments tell us L ∝ n³?

Comment: Hint: more loops - more magnetic field - more energy stored. So I don't know where is your **Theoretically** is coming from.

Comment: @Neil_UK And a double-long wire doubles the magnetic density(just I guess). As a result, the voltage produced on **per length** of the wire is doubled. With the length doubled and voltage on per length doubled, the total back EMF is quadrupled(2²). Am I right?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Hmm……Yes, energy is another point of view. I suppose n times more loops products n times stronger magnetic field, and thus n times more energy is stored in it. But how does this lead to n² bigger L?

Comment: @NickAlexeev Seems that I 've got it: *magnetic flux* ∝ n, while *magnetic flux linkage* ∝ n².

Comment: @sunqingyao Yes, twice as many turns is twice as much flux, twice as many turns is twice as much EMF per flux is 4 times as much EMF per current is 4x as much inductance.